# Access Query Criteria Creating Parameter Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am having a problem with a query that uses iif statements per the below:

Items to Exclude: IIf([Is this FAC]="No",[ID2],IIf(([Is this FAC]="Yes") And ([ID2]="CsaId"),"False",[ID2]))

The above 'Items to Exclude' field should populate ID2 where the 'Is this FAC' field is (1) No OR (2) is Yes AND ID2 is not 'CsaId'.

When the Query is run with the above formulas and as per the below it works fine, returning FALSE where it should in the 'Items to Exclude' field per the formula.

[image]

The problem is if I then enter <>"False" in the Criteria field per the below (as I want to then filter out any exclusions, i.e. False items)

[image]

it seems to turn  the field into a parameter query and gives a window pop up per the below instead of just filtering out the FALSE statements.

[image]

I would appreciate any help/ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses you cannot use column aliases like you did. Replace all `Is this FAC` by formula for this column. So, in your case for Items to Exclude the formula will be

```
Items to Exclude: IIf(IIf([Id1]="FAC","Yes","No")="No",[ID2],
    IIf((IIf([Id1]="FAC","Yes","No")="Yes") And ([ID2]="CsaId"),"False",[ID2]))
```

After this condition will work.You can think about simplifying this formula.

Also you can save your query without criteria and then use it as subquery for filtering out unnecessary records.

Comment: Hi Sergey. Thanks for your comments. When you say 'Replace by formula for this column' do you mean refer to the column in some other way than referring to it with the Field name [Is this FAC]?

Comment: If so, how would you suggest referring to it please as an example, as I don't think i know of another way? Cheers